# Date not getting entered in mysql(0000-00-00) using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
$dat=date("Y-m-d");
```

This is how date is being fetched in PHP

```
insert into gd_purchase(Product_Model,Purchase_Date,Purchase_Quantity) values('22P413',2016-12-27,20)
```

When above query is fired date is entered as 0000-00-00 in mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the date value with single quotes like this:

```
insert into gd_purchase(Product_Model,Purchase_Date,Purchase_Quantity) 
values('22P413','2016-12-27',20)
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to add date part in quotes:

```
insert into gd_purchase(Product_Model,Purchase_Date,Purchase_Quantity) values('22P413','2016-12-27',20)
```